# Variables are continuously zero while creating matrice with for loop

Tags: matlab, matrix

Here is my code;

```
%Blasius solution by Euler Method
%---------------
g0=zeros(101,1);
g1=zeros(101,1);
g2=zeros(101,1);
%---------------
g0(1)=0;
g1(1)=0;
% g1(101)=1;
g2(1)=2;
%---------------
G=zeros(101,3);
T=zeros(101,3);
G=[g0 g1 g2];
T=[g1 g2 (-1)*g0.*g2];
%Euler method%
for i=1:100
G(i+1) = G(i) + (T(i)*0.1);
end
```

What am I missing? I am trying to create the `G` matrix but it is always a `101*3` zero matrix. It looks like for loop doesn't work but I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: You might want to specify whether to take columns or rows in your indices, as opposed to using plain linear ones. Also, your T is always zero, since you multiply zero-elements with zero elements and once with a 2, which is still zero. In your loop you are adding and multiplying zeroes with zeroes, so obviously the result is zero.

Comment: Okey here is the thing;

G(1)=[0 0 2]

then G(2) =[0 0 2]+[0 2 0]*0.1=[0 0.2 2]

G(3)= [0 0.2 2]+(0.2 2 0]*0.1 =[0.2 2.2 2]

It suppose to get rid of zeros after third line?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why your code is not working:

First of all you need to call row indices, not linear indices, i.e. change your loop to:

```
for ii=1:100
    G(ii+1,:) = G(ii,:) + (T(ii,:)*0.1);
end
```

note that I also used `ii` as opposed to `i`, since [using that as a variable is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

This results in `T` remaining constant, obviously, since you *do not change it*. You initialise it as a zero array and set only the second element on the first row to `2`, but leave the rest as zeros. Adding a row of `T` to a row of `G` will therefore not do anything, since you are adding zeros to an existing row. This is why the second row of `G` becomes `[0 0.2 2]` and *does not change anymore* , since you are only adding zeros to it.

You probably forgot to add the line of code which assigns a new value to rows of `T`. Adhering to your suggestion in the comments:

```
for ii=1:100
    G(ii+1,:) = G(ii,:) + (T(ii,:)*0.1);
    T(ii+1,:) = G(ii,:);
end
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your interest. My code is just like that actually i do not forget anything to write in here, as you can see i am a beginner. 
I have change the for loop but i do not understand how to assing new T and where should i do that. Is it going to be look like that?
`G(ii,2)=T(ii,1)`
Where should i assing that? Is is going to be in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new solution, we have spend hours but finally figure it out.

```
%Blasius solution by Euler Method
%---------------
g0=zeros(101,1);
g1=zeros(101,1);
g2=zeros(101,1);
g2(1)=2;
%---------------
G=zeros(101,3);
T=zeros(101,3);
G=[g0 g1 g2];
T=[g1 g2 ((-1)*g0.*g2)];
 %Euler method%
for i=1:100
A=[g0(i) g1(i) g2(i)] ;
B=[g1(i)*0.1 g2(i)*0.1 (-1).*g0(i)*g2(i)*0.1];
C(i,:)=A+B;
g0(i+1)=C(i,1);
g1(i+1) =C(i,2);
g2(i+1) =C(i,3);
end
```